# Make custom HTML in iWeb appear sanely

Tags: html, iweb

I'm trying to improve the layout of a colleague's site. He's not technical and is using iWeb. Naively I tried embedding a dropdown menu in an HTML snippet and the result was pretty awful; you can't see it in the desktop version and I had to leave, but iWeb was shifting the entire menu 50000 pixels left.

Are there any tricks for making custom HTML lay out properly in iWeb or should I try to convince my colleague to switch? Are there any other GUI desktop tools with one-click FTP deploys?

Comment: i have never bothered to use iWeb, but by chance can you add in stylesheets? and if so, try using a reset stylesheet. maybe that could help.

Comment: I tried that - my HTML snippet had `<style>/* my menu styles */</style><ul id="nav">...` and there were still lots of layout issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried multiple times and had many many people ask me about this (I used to do technical support on Mac computers) and there is not a way to accomplish this easily.

They can definitely try Freeway Express which gives a lot more options for things like you are trying to do as well as easy FTP uploads! [Check out Freeway!](http://www.softpress.com/products/freewayexpress/)

Also, FYI, if they are using MobileMe to host that, hosting will be gone when MobileMe support ends!

Comment: Nope, they're using Godaddy, and don't know anything about HTML, just want to be able to drag & drop photos & text and have them show up on the Internet.